# how to implement @MappedSuperClass in squeryl?

Tags: scala, squeryl

I have 12 tables in the database. and all tables has same columns and same relations.

So I had writen the code in JPA.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseAddress {
... properties and relations (@ManyToOne / @OneToMany)
}

@Entity
public class Address1 extends BaseAddress {
  // has no code. properties and relations are inherited.
}

@Entity 
public class Address2 extends BaseAddress {
  // has no code. properties and relations are inherited.    
}
```

but, I don't know how implemented it in squeryl schema definition.
How implement that relation inheritance in squeryl ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squeryl will reflect on all of the available fields.  It doesn't make a distinction on whether they are inherited or not.  Something like:

```
class BaseAddress(id: Long, address: String)

class Address1(id: Long, address: String) extends BaseAddress(id, address)

class Address2(id: Long, address: String) extends BaseAddress(id, address)

object MySchema extends Schema {

  val address1 = table[Address1]

  val address2 = table[Address2]

}
```

Should work similarly to the Hibernate code you posted.  For the relationships, with Squeryl they are defined in the Schema object rather than within the model class.  You can add a helper method if you're defining the same relation more than once:

```
def addressTableWithUserRelation[T <: BaseAddress]: (Table[T], OneToManyRelation[User, T]) = {
  val table = Table[T]
  val relation = oneToManyRelation(users, table)((u,t) => u.id === t.userId)
  (table, relation)
}

val (address1, address1ToUser) = addressTableWithUserRelation[Address1]
```